# Laravel pushing assets to the public directory

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php

So today I started learning Laravel & composer (before I was using Yii). I installed with composer so my directory structure is:

- app
- bootstrap
- components
- public
- vendor

I need to include bootstrap and I wanted to be as much professional as it can be, so I  added the 
`"components/bootstrap": "dev-master"` string in `"require"` section. But the components folder is not accessible from the "outside" how can I push the composer installed assets to the public directory?

Comment: Maybe you can use [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#package-assets). However I don't know if that only works with "Larvel optimized" packages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "components/bootstrap" is the correct package.

Try https://github.com/buonzz-systems/laravel-twitter-bootstrap

After running

```
php artisan asset:publish
```

should push bootstrap to the public/packages folder

But since you are new, I say just load the bootstrap manually by copying it to the public folder.